# 120v 60hz 8w input, 6 v 800ma mains adaptor, what is the equivalent here in oz on 240 v?

Tags: conversion, wall-wart

Title says it all, Ive got many an adaptor lying around, do I need another 6v .8a at 240v?

I should note ive had it plugged into the mains with a standard international adaptor for over three years now no problem. looking to lose the adaptor.

Comment: It seems as though you're using "adapter" in two different senses here, making your question extremely difficult to follow. Could you be more explicit about what you're trying to do?

Comment: sorry, wallwart is 120v, using international adaptor to change plug configuration from us to aus.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Show us what you have and which part of it you want to "lose".

Comment: Please read the answer linked in @PeterJ's comment. It is worth your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 240V AC to 6V DC 800mA adapter. On the output side you need the 6V and 800mA regardless of what is on the input side. A lot of AC adapters can handle both 120V and 240V. Check the input specification printed on the adapter.  If it can accept 240V then all you need is a physical plug converter.

Comment: it doesnt say 240v just 120. So voltage makes no difference?

Comment: That isn't what he said. Voltage most definitely *does* make a difference. Some wallwarts can work on any voltage from 120V to 240V, while others are 120V only or 240V only. If your "international adapter" is just a *physical* adapter for the plug, then your wallwart is already operating at 240V. If the adapter is a transformer of some sort, then you need to find a new wallwart that accepts 240V AC and produces 6V DC at a minimum of 800 mA. What exactly are you trying to "lose"?